# "No matching functions to call to" happen to constructors in C++

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

Here is C++ constructor problem I have in my program.

The problem occurs here, the constructor of *cyclical_* is not detected in the program. Here

```
pcl::gpu::kinfuLS::KinfuTracker::KinfuTracker 
(   const Eigen::Vector3f &volume_size, const float shiftingDistance, 
    int rows, int cols) : 
    //
    // error lies here, no matching function for cyclical_()
    //
        cyclical_( DISTANCE_THRESHOLD, VOLUME_SIZE, VOLUME_X ),  
        rows_(rows), cols_(cols), global_time_(0), max_icp_distance_(0), 
        integration_metric_threshold_(0.f), 
        perform_last_scan_ (false), finished_(false), lost_ (false), 
        disable_icp_ (false), perform_segmentation_(false)
{
  ....
}
```

The cyclical_ class is well defined and referred. It is defined as the one below. The full original full is here. https://github.com/lvzhaoyang/pcl/blob/master/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/include/pcl/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/kinfu.h
I added some parameters to my program, but I didn't change anything related to the CyclicalBuffer.

```
CyclicalBuffer cyclical_;
CyclicalBuffer object_cyclical_; // another member of type CyclicalBuffer, but the error shows the former one, not this one. Someone say it might affect.
enum { VOLUME_X = 512, VOLUME_Y = 512, VOLUME_Z = 512 };
const float VOLUME_SIZE = 3.0f;
const float DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 1.5f;
```

And the CyclicalBuffer class is defined as follows. The original one is here:https://github.com/lvzhaoyang/pcl/blob/master/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/include/pcl/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/cyclical_buffer.h This part I didn't change anything.

```
namespace pcl
{
namespace gpu
{
namespace kinfuLS
{ 
  class PCL_EXPORTS CyclicalBuffer
  {
    public:

      CyclicalBuffer (const double distance_threshold, const double cube_size = 3.f, const int nb_voxels_per_axis = 512)
      {
        distance_threshold_ = distance_threshold;
        buffer_.volume_size.x = cube_size; 
        buffer_.volume_size.y = cube_size; 
        buffer_.volume_size.z = cube_size;
        buffer_.voxels_size.x = nb_voxels_per_axis; 
        buffer_.voxels_size.y = nb_voxels_per_axis; 
        buffer_.voxels_size.z = nb_voxels_per_axis; 
      }

      CyclicalBuffer (const double distance_threshold, const double volume_size_x, const double volume_size_y, const double volume_size_z, const int nb_voxels_x, const int nb_voxels_y, const int nb_voxels_z)
      {
        distance_threshold_ = distance_threshold;
        buffer_.volume_size.x = volume_size_x; 
        buffer_.volume_size.y = volume_size_y; 
        buffer_.volume_size.z = volume_size_z;
        buffer_.voxels_size.x = nb_voxels_x; 
        buffer_.voxels_size.y = nb_voxels_y; 
        buffer_.voxels_size.z = nb_voxels_z; 
      }

  ...

}
}
};
```

But when I compile the problem, it gives such error:

```
/home/lv/pcl-trunk/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/src/kinfu.cpp: In constructor ‘pcl::gpu::kinfuLS::KinfuTracker::KinfuTracker(const Vector3f&, float, int, int)’:
/home/lv/pcl-trunk/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/src/kinfu.cpp:85:53: error: no matching function for call to ‘pcl::gpu::kinfuLS::CyclicalBuffer::CyclicalBuffer()’
/home/lv/pcl-trunk/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/src/kinfu.cpp:85:53: note: candidates are:
/home/lv/pcl-trunk/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/include/pcl/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/cyclical_buffer.h:96:11: note: pcl::gpu::kinfuLS::CyclicalBuffer::CyclicalBuffer(double, double, double, double, int, int, int)
/home/lv/pcl-trunk/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/include/pcl/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/cyclical_buffer.h:96:11: note:   candidate expects 7 arguments, 0 provided
/home/lv/pcl-trunk/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/include/pcl/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/cyclical_buffer.h:75:11: note: pcl::gpu::kinfuLS::CyclicalBuffer::CyclicalBuffer(double, double, int)
/home/lv/pcl-trunk/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/include/pcl/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/cyclical_buffer.h:75:11: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
/home/lv/pcl-trunk/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/include/pcl/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/cyclical_buffer.h:65:25: note: pcl::gpu::kinfuLS::CyclicalBuffer::CyclicalBuffer(const pcl::gpu::kinfuLS::CyclicalBuffer&)
/home/lv/pcl-trunk/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/include/pcl/gpu/kinfu_large_scale/cyclical_buffer.h:65:25: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

I don't quite catch the error that *candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided*. I think I have provided the right number of arguments and everything is clearly referred.

Thank you for a discussion about my problem. I think I find some clues but I don't know why. The problem may lies on the second member of type CyclicalBuffer.

```
CyclicalBuffer cyclical_;
CyclicalBuffer object_cyclical_; // when I comment everything related to this. The error disappears.
```

It seems weird. I don't know how a second member gives a error on the first member. If it is the problem that object_cyclical_ is not correctly constructed, why will it report errors on cyclical_? To make sure, the error report line 85 is the line of cyclical_( DISTANCE_THRESHOLD, VOLUME_SIZE, VOLUME_X )

Could anyone help me point out what potential problem it lies?

Comment: CyclicalBuffer has a missing semicolon on the end of the class - you have put it on the namespace closing brace, but I don't think that's the problem

Comment: Could you mark what line 85 is in the code you show here? Is it the line where you're initializing `cyclical_`? Are there other constructors for `KinfuTracker` you don't show?

Comment: I think you need to show us the whole definition of `KinfuTracker` (the part in your header) because there doesn't seem anything wrong in the code you showed us.

Comment: line 85 is the line I make the comment in the beginning, the cyclical_() constructor fails

Comment: Can you show us the whole header file for KinfuTracker?

Comment: This line `CyclicalBuffer cyclical_;` will call the default constructor.

Comment: The original header is too long and may confuse you. I just pasted the relevant part. Can Anyone explain what does the error mean? Why does it say "0 provided"?

Comment: Does `KinfuTracker` have any other members of type `CyclicalBuffer`?

Comment: Yes I forget say this, it has another member of type CyclicalBuffer. How does it matter? I will add this in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piecing things together, I think what you have is this (simplified by leaving out some of the namespace bits for now):

```
class KinfuTracker
{ // ....
  CyclicalBuffer cyclical_;
  CyclicalBuffer object_cyclical_;
  // ....
};

KinfuTracker::KinfuTracker(/*arguments left out for simplicity*/) : 
   cyclical_( DISTANCE_THRESHOLD, VOLUME_SIZE, VOLUME_X ),
   /* other member constructor/initializer bits */
{ // ......
}
```

What I think is causing your problem is not with `cyclical_`, but with `object_cyclical_`. `object_cyclical_` does not appear in the constructor/initializer list, so it is being constructed via default constructor, which you have not implemented.

Either provide a default constructor for `CyclicalBuffer`, that sets reasonable default values, or explicitly construct the `object_cyclical_` member in your `KinfoTracker` class.

Answer (score 2):

Just as Todd Murray mentioned in the comments, the line `CyclicalBuffer cyclical_;` invokes a constructor with zero arguments, `CyclicalBuffer()`.  Since your code does not define a default constructor with zero arguments, the compiler does not implicitly define a default constructor.  This results in an error when you simply declare `cyclical_`.  Therefore you need to either create a zero-argument constructor, or change your code so you are initializing `cyclical_` with the correct number of arguments when you declare it.

Example:

Simply switching around some of your code and adding the correct construction should produce a working code.

```
enum { VOLUME_X = 512, VOLUME_Y = 512, VOLUME_Z = 512 };
const float VOLUME_SIZE = 3.0f;
const float DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 1.5f;
CyclicalBuffer cyclical_ = new CyclicalBuffer(DISTANCE_THRESHOLD, VOLUME_SIZE, VOLUME_X);
```

Comment: cyclical_ has a 3 arguments constructor. At the beginning, it is not initialized, and it also has a right-type initializer with 3 arguments. I'm sorry I don't catch your point.

Comment: Yes it may have three arguments in your `pcl::gpu::kinfuLS::KinfuTracker::KinfuTracker` function, but when you declare `cyclical_`, you are not giving any arguments which results in attempting to call `CyclicalBuffer()` (zero-argument constructor), which does not exist.

Comment: But why will it give error on the line in pcl::gpu::kinfuLS::KinfuTracker::KinfuTracker. And I add some clues in the question. Will it help?

Comment: I think I catch your point. Your are right. The problem is caused by another member invoking a wrong constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you call default constructor of `CyclicalBuffer` (with no arguments):

```
no matching function for call to 
‘pcl::gpu::kinfuLS::CyclicalBuffer::CyclicalBuffer()’
```

but class `CyclicalBuffer` doesn't have such constructor.

Compiler can only find constructors with 3, 7 arguments and copy-constructor (with 1 argument). 
So it tests all this 3 candidates, but cannot find matching one, because you calling constructor without arguments (0 arguments provided).

Search trough your code and find place where default constructor called.

If you have `CyclicalBuffer` member, but not initializing it in constructor of your class, default constructor called, which is not possible, because `CyclicalBuffer` doesn't have it. Example:

```
struct Data
{
    Data(int, int) {}
    int x, y;
};

struct MyClass
{
    MyClass() {} // error C2512: 'Data' : no appropriate default constructor available
    Data data;
};

struct MyClass2
{
    MyClass(): 
        data(41, 13) // OK
    {} 
    Data data;
};
```

If I understand right, class already had `cyclicalbuffer_` member, which was initialized in constructor initializer list. But you added one more such member and didn't initialized it.